# Threading issues in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt4

I have asked this problem on many popular forums but no concrete response. My applciation uses serial communication to interface with external systems each having its own interface protocol. The data that is received from the systems is displayed on a GUI made in Qt 4.2.1.

Structure of application is such that

1. When app begins we have a login page
   with a choice of four modules. This
   is implemented as a maindisplay
   class. Each of the four modules is a
   separate class in itself. The concerned module here is of action class which is responsible of gathering and displaying data from various systems.
2. User authentication gets him/her
   into the action screen. The
   constructor of the action screen
   class executes and apart from
   mundane initialisation it starts the
   individual systems threads which are
   implemented as singleton.

Each system protocol is implemented as a singleton thread of the form:

```
class SensorProtocol:public QThread {    
    static SensorProtocol* s_instance;
    SensorProtocol(){}
    SensorProtocol(const SensorProtocol&);
    operator=(const SensorProtocol&);

public:
    static SensorProtocol* getInstance();
    //miscellaneous system related data to be used for
    // data acquisition and processing
};
```

In implementation file *.cpp:

```
SensorProtocol* SensorProtocol::s_instance=0;
SensorProtocol* SensorProtocol::getInstance()
{
   //DOUBLE CHECKED LOCKING PATTERN I have used singletons
   // without this overrated pattern also but just fyi  
   if(!s_instance)
   {
       mutex.lock();
       if(!s_instance) 
           s_instance=new SensorProtocol();
       mutex.unlock();
   } 
}
```

Structure of run function

```
while(!mStop)
{
  mutex.lock()
  while(!WaitCondition.wait(&mutex,5)
  {
      if(mStop)
      return;    
  }

  //code to read from port when data becomes available
  // and process it and store in variables
  mutex.unlock();
}
```

In the action screen class I have define an InputSignalHandler using sigaction and saio. This is a function pointer which is activated as soon as data arrives on any of the serial ports.

It is a global function (we cannot change it as it is specific to Linux) which is just used to compare the file descriptors of the serial port where data has arrived and the fd's of the sensor systems,  if a match is found WaitCondition.wakeOne is invoked on that thread and it comes out the wait and reads and processes the data.

In the action screen class the individual threads are started as `SensorProtocol::getInstance()->start()`.

Each system's protocol has a frame rate at which it sends data. Based on this fact, in actions screen we set up update timers to time out at refresh rate of protocols. When these timers time out the UpdateSensorProtocol() function of operation screen is called

```
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout), this,SLOT(UpdateSensorProtocol()));
```

This grabs an instance of sensor singleton as

```
SensorProtocol* pSingleton=SensorProtocol::getInstance();
if(pSingleton->mUpdate)
{
    //update data on action screen GUI
   pSingleton->mUpdate=false;  //NOTE : this variable is set to
                               // true in the singleton thread
                               // while one frame is processed completely
}
```

For all uses of singleton instance `SensorProtocol::getInstance()` is used. Given the above scenario, One of my protocols is hanging no matter what changes I do.

The hang occurs in the while displaying data using UpdateSensorProtocol() If I comment `ShowSensorData()` function in the `UpdateSensorProtocol()` it works fine. But otherwise it hangs and the GUI freezes. Any suggestions!

Also, Since the main thread grabs the running instance of singleton, is it really multithreading because we are essentially changing mUpdate in singleton itself albeit from action screen.

I am confused in this.

Also, Can somebody suggest an alternate design as to what I am doing now.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Are you calling ShowSensorData from the GUI or I/O thread? The singleton really has nothing to do with the thread context...

Comment: Why are you (mis)using the singleton pattern in the first place?

Comment: I am calling ShowSensorData function from UpdateSensorData() which is a GUI class member function. Can you correct me as to how singleton should be used here. I have also tried using Meyers Singleton with static local instance but no luck, besides it brings additional problems in my case.

Comment: I'm questioning your reason for using a singleton pattern in the first place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off all don't make the Systems singletons.  Use some kind of [Context Encapsulation](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/europlop/ContextEncapsulation.pdf)
  for the different system.

If you ignoe this advice and still want to create "singletons" threads at least use `QApplication::instance();` as the parent of the thread and put `QThread::wait()` in the singleton destructors otherwise your program will crash at the program exit.

```
if(!s_instance){
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    if(!s_instance) 
        s_instance=new SensorProtocol( QApplication::instance());
}
```

But this isn't going to solve your problem ...
Qt is event driven so try to exployed this very nice event-driven architecture and create a eventloop for each system thread.  Then you can create "SystemProtocols" that live in another threads and you can create timers, send events between threads, ... without using low level synchronization objects.  
Have a look at the blog entry from Bradley T. Hughes [Treading without the headache](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/)

Code is not compiled but should give you a good idea where to start ...

```
class GuiComponent : public QWidget {
    //...
signals: 
    void start(int); // button triggerd signal
    void stop();     // button triggerd singal 

public slots:
    // don't forget to register DataPackage at the metacompiler
    // qRegisterMetaType<DataPackage>();
    void dataFromProtocol( DataPackage ){
        // update the gui the the new data 
    }
};

class ProtocolSystem : public QObject {
     //...
    int timerId;

signals:
    void dataReady(DataPackage);

public slots:
    void stop() {
       killTimer(timerId);  
    }

    void start( int interval ) {
       timerId = startTimer();  
    }

protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * event) {
       //code to read from port when data becomes available
       // and process it and store in dataPackage
       emit dataReady(dataPackage);
    }
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    // construct the system and glue them together
    ProtocolSystem protocolSystem;
    GuiComponent gui;
    gui.connect(&protocolSystem, SIGNAL(dataReady(DataPackage)), SLOT(dataFromProtocol(DataPackage)));
    protocolSystem.connect(&gui, SIGNAL(start(int)), SLOT(start(int)));
    protocolSystem.connect(&gui, SIGNAL(stop()), SLOT(stop()));
    // move communication to its thread
    QThread protocolThread;
    protocolSystem.moveToThread(&protocolThread);
    protocolThread.start(); 
    // repeat this for other systems ...
    // start the application
    gui.show();
    app.exec();
    // stop eventloop to before closing the application
    protocolThread.quit();
    protocolThread.wait();
    return 0;    
}
```

Now you have total independent systems, gui and protocols don't now each other and don't even know that the program is multithreaded.  You can unit test all systems independently  in a single threaded environement and just glue them together in the real application and if you need to, divided them between different threads. 
That is the program architecture that I would use for this problem.  Mutlithreading without a single low level synchronization element. No race conditions, no locks, ...

Comment: Wow!!! thats quite a perspective! and the paper on Context encapsulation is amazing. Man I couldn't think of it, even one bit.

Comment: I'm glad I could help ... I believe almost everyone has the same feeling the first time.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problems:

Use RAII to lock/unlock your mutexes. They are currently not exception safe.

```
while(!mStop)
{
  mutex.lock()

  while(!WaitCondition.wait(&mutex,5))
  {
    if(mStop)
    {   
        // PROBLEM 1: You mutex is still locked here.
        // So returning here will leave the mutex locked forever.
        return;    
    }

    // PROBLEM 2: If you leave here via an exception.
    // This will not fire, and again you will the mutex locked forever.
    mutex.unlock();

    // Problem 3: You are using the WaitCondition() incorrectly.
    // You unlock the mutex here. The next thing that happens is a call
    // WaitCondition.wait() where the mutex MUST be locked
 }
 // PROBLEM 4
 // You are using the WaitCondition() incorrectly.
 // On exit the mutex is always locked. So nwo the mutex is locked.
```

What your code should look like:

```
while(!mStop)
{
  MutextLocker   lock(mutex);  // RAII lock and unlock mutex.

  while(!WaitCondition.wait(&mutex,5))
  {
    if(mStop)
    {   
        return;    
    }

    //code to read from port when data becomes available
    // and process it and store in variables
 }
```

By using RAII it solves all the problems I spotted above.

#### On a side note.

Your double checked locking will not work correctly.
By using the static function variable suggested by 'Anders Karlsson' you solve the problem because g++ guarantees that static function variables will only be initialized once. In addition this method guaranteed that the singelton will be correctly destroyed (via destructor). Currently unless you are doing some fancy stuff via onexit() you will be leaking memory.

See here for lots of details about better implementation of singleton.
[C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289)

See here why your double checked locking does not work.
[What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-c-programmer-should-know-about/367690#367690)

Comment: Thank you very much York. I have made the change and waiting for the result. One thing is for sure. As soon as I solve this issue, I will definitely post it in this thread. Because I have been stuck here for 2 months now. Tried every trick in the book. The only thing left to change is design :-)) which will be a PIA since only a month is left for delivery.

Comment: +1 Very nice catch Martin. I didn't even notice the misuse of the condition variable.

Comment: Should "MutextLocker" be "MutexLocker" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) to improve the safety of your locking code. You have code that look like this:

```
mutex.lock();
...logic...
mutex.unlock();
```

Wrap the mutex code inside a class where the mutex gets acquired in the ctor and released in the dtor. Now your code looks like this:

```
MyMutex mutex;
...logic...
```

The major improvement is that if any exceptions throw in the logic part, your mutex still gets released.

Also, don't let any exceptions leak out of your threads! Catch them even if you don't know how to handle them other than logging it somewhere.

Comment: There is a limitation with using waitcondition in Qt. The method that I have used for mutex locking is the only one for using waitconditions. RAII cannot be used here I guess. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am probably going to look at Qt in the near future, especially since they are moving into the mobile space.

Comment: You can and you ->should<- use RAII here. Otherwise the code is not exception safe.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was some dark magic inside Qt that changed the rules of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be completely sure what the problem is since I have no clue what the `ShowSensorData()` function (method?) is doing, but there are some multithreading issues with the code that you have included.

1. `mUpdate` should be protected by a mutex if it is accessed by more than one thread.
2. The `run()` method looks like it will lock the mutex and never release it if `mStop` is true.

You should consider using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) practices to grab and release the mutex. I don't know if you are using Qt mutexes or not but you should look into using [QMutexLocker](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmutexlocker.html) to lock and unlock your mutexes.

I would consider changing your `SensorProtocol` class to use the condition variable and a flag or some sort of event (not sure what Qt has to offer here) to handle the update inside of a method associated with the object instance. Something like:

```
/*static*/ void
SensorProtocol::updateSensorProtocol() {
    SensorProtocol *inst = SensorProtocol::getInstance();
    inst->update();
}
```

Then make sure that the `update()` method grabs the mutex before reading or writing any of the members that are shared between the reader and display.

A more complete approach would be to separate your UI display, the sensors, and their linkage using a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture. Refactoring the solution into an MVC architecture would probably simplify things quite a bit. Not to mention that it makes applications like this a lot less error-prone. Take a look at the [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qabstractitemview.html) and [QAbstractItemDelegate](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qabstractitemdelegate.html) classes for an idea on how this can be implemented. From what I remember, there is a tutorial about implementing MVC using Qt somewhere... it's been quite a few years since I have played with Qt though.

Comment: As for your point 1. I did use mutexes but no luck, hung as usual As for point 2. mStop becomes true only when I close action screen so that is a non-issue in my case. Besides the point, can you suggest an alternate implementation for the app. I will surely look in the MVC architecture that you have mentioned. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QextSerialPort](http://qextserialport.sourceforge.net/):

> QextSerialPort is a cross-platform
>   serial port class. This class
>   encapsulates a serial port on both
>   POSIX and Windows systems.

[QextSerialPort](http://qextserialport.sourceforge.net/qextserialport-1.1.x/) inherits from [QIODevice](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qiodevice.html) and makes serial port communications integrate more smoothly with the rest of the Qt API.

Also, you could use a message passing scheme for communications between the I/O and GUI threads instead of shared memory. This is often much less error prone. You can use the [QApplication::postEvent](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) function to send custom QEvent messages to a QObject to be processed in the GUI thread with the [QObject::customeEvent](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qobject.html#customEvent) handler. It will take care of synchronization for you and alleviate your deadlock problems..

Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
class IODataEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    IODataEvent() : QEvent(QEvent::User) {}

    // put all of your data here
};

class IOThread : public QThread
{
public:
    IOThread(QObject * parent) : QThread(parent) {}

    void run()
    {
    for (;;) {
            // do blocking I/O and protocol parsing
            IODataEvent *event = new IODataEvent;
            // put all of your data for the GUI into the event
            qApp->postEvent(parent(), event);
            // QApplication will take ownership of the event
        }
    }
};

class GUIObject : public QObject
{
public:
    GUIObject() : QObject(), thread(new IOThread(this)) { thread->start() }

protected:
    void customEvent(QEvent *event)
    {
        if (QEvent::User == event->type) {
            IODataEvent *data = (IODataEvent *) event;
            // get data and update GUI here
            event->accept();
        } else {
            event->ignore();
        }
        // the event loop will release the IODataEvent memory automatically
    }

private:
    IOThread *thread;
};
```

Also, Qt 4 [supports queing signals and slots across threads](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

Comment: I have heard about QextSerialPort but since it is a 3rd party class I cannot use it because what if it brings out additional issues, besides the whole design of my app would change.

Comment: Isn't your question how to change the design of your application? ;)

Answer (score 0):

your getInstance method could maybe be written like this as well to avoid having the s_instance var:

```
SensorProtocol& getInstance()
{
  static SensorProtocol instance;
  return instance;
}
```

Comment: This is meyers singleton, I have tried it with no luck, also it brings an additional headache in my case + already existing hanging problem

Answer (score 0):

The double checked locking pattern is broken in C++. This is well documented all over the internet. I don't know what your problem is but clearly you will need to resolve this in your code.

Comment: What's the point of even attempting it when the singleton could be explicitly instantiated before multiple threads are started?!? Singletons generally suck except for very few exceptions in my humble opinion.

Comment: DCLP isn't needed here, because problem is elsewhere. Also if you say Singletons are bad,can you suggest an alternative in my case.

Comment: I didn't say anything about singletons - I'm just pointing out that you should not ever use DCLP as this is guaranteed to be fail to work on some combination of compilers/CPUs

Answer (score 0):

Have three sepearate threads for send, receive and display.

Raise an event whenever data is received and handle that within the display thread.

**Edit in response to comment 1**

I'll admit that I know nothing of qt but from what you've said it would still appear that you can create your serial port object which in turn starts up two worker threads (by use of a start method) for the input and output buffer control.

If the serial port class has a "Connect to port" method to gain use of the serial port; an "Open port" method which starts up your worker threads and opens the port; a "Close port" method to shutdown the send and receive threads and a property for setting the "On Data Received" event handler then you should be all set.

The class shouldn't need to be a singleton as you'll find that most operating systems wont allow more than one process to control a serial port at any one time, instead you'll get an exception (which you need to handle) when you try and connect if it is already in use. The worker threads ensure that the port is held under you're control.

Comment: In Qt there is only one GUI thread which handles display, this is the maing thread when the application starts, all other threads have to be started from this thread only. This constraint is what put constraints on the design of the app. To periodically check for sensor data I have to get its object and examine it data. This essentially creates two instances of the sensor one running and other motionless. For this limitation I guess we used singleton